# VirtualBox cannot ping Windows7 (host), Windows XP (guest)

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, ping, hosts

I have successfully installed a Windows XP OS on VirtualBox with Windows 7 as host.

The Windows XP guest is able to navigate on the Internet but I'm not able to ping the guest from the host and vice-versa.

I need this working because I have to test a client/server application.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

You have most likely configured your guest's network adapter in NAT mode.

Shut your guest down.

Go to the Guest's network settings and in the Adapter settings change the `Attached to: NAT` to `Attached to: Bridged Adaptor`.

Start your guest

Your guest should now pick up an address from your main network.

**EDIT** 
To find the adaptor settings, in the Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager click on your guest. On the right you will see a series of panels. Click on the Network Panel. A pop-up will apear with the settings in.

**EDIT**
Here is a blog post with some images attached: http://house9.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/ping-guest-os-from-host-os-with.html

Comment: Where I can find the "Adapter settings"?

Comment: @carlo: See my edit

Comment: Ok, but I don't find "Attached to: Bridged Adaptor" only "NAT"

Comment: @carlo: Click on the NAT - it's a drop down selection.

Comment: yes, sure :-) , but is not present the entry "Bridged Adaptor"

Comment: @carlo, if all else fails - read the documentation.

Comment: @john, thank you for your support, I'm really don't know where find this information.

Comment: @carlo - bridged networking support is usually installed by default. If you don't have it, did you disable it's installation when you installed VB ? Try running the installer again and ensuring that bridged networking is installed.

Comment: yes, may be this is the problem. I found an article on internet that is present the "Attached to: Bridged Adapter" entry. Now I reinstalling VB, and I will return here, for a feedback to you

Comment: I have reinstalled VB, ensure that bridged networking support is installed, but nothing to do, is not present the entry "Attached to". May be is the version of the guest O.S. that I have installed. I have no idea how to go ahead.

Comment: Why I don't have "Attached to" functionality? Very very strange. I'm really frustrated

Comment: I don't know all the available installations I have, have bridged available.

Comment: I have download 4 times the last version of VB from the offical site but don't have the bridged available

Comment: Is possible to have a link where I can download the right version? Thanks!